# Inline-block divs on different levels

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I have two `div` that both have `"display: inline-block"`. Though, those are displayed on different `height`. I have a feeling that I've solved this issue before, but I can't remember how. Please help.[image]

Comment: what you have problem with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use verticle-align property to make them align. You can use top, middle and bottom as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Elements with inline-block set will wrap to the next line of the browser window if space for the current line cant fit the remaining elements - in this case the red div. I also see extra left spacing/padding from the 'Test Product' div. I think both divs will align at the same line if you remove the spacing/padding. It would be helpful if you can post your html code though.